# Multiple gestures on same view (drag view out of scrollable view) not working the right way?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

In order to let my panGesture (attached to an `UIImageView`) to be called, I need to make sure that the user is not scrolling in the horizontal `ScrollView` the image lies within. I am achieving this like so:

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePan(_:)))
    panGesture.require(toFail: self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

This works well but as the `scrollView` is **horizontal only**, it only allows the panGesture to work horizontally. I want to also pull the UIImage vertically, but nothing happens because obviously,  it will only be called if the scroll view fails (can only fail horizontally).

Is there a way to make sure it so that the above works but also allows the `panGesture` to be called **vertically** no matter what?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you have a UIImageView(s) inside a horizontal UIScrollView. Are you trying to *move* the image someplace? Maybe you could replace the scrollview with a horizontal stack view? Just trying to brainstorm. It sounds complex to use a pan gesture on the content of a scroll view.

Comment: @dfd I have a filter gallery in scrollview. What I want to do is allow the user to scroll left and right to browse the gallery and if they like a filter, to hold and pan it out (vertically) and drag onto another view. The problem is that the pan gesture recognizer keeps cancelling the ability to scroll left and right. It thinks I want to take the uiimage and pan it. You know what I mean?

Comment: That's a challenging one. My app (and the next few) will be photo effects so I *do* know what you mean. Several apps do something like that. I do understand what you are trying - I think. *I think.* (1) By what you want, what does "pan it out" mean? I'm speaking in technical terms. Obviously they've *selected* something. But then... what? Specifically. Are they "dragging the filtered image" to another view? (2) Again, specifically speaking, what app already does what you want? Mental images help here. You simply **cannot** drag a subview from one superview to another. So what *can* be done?

Comment: Going from there, a few more thoughts. Assuming you cannot "drag" one's subview into another's, how to you make it *appear* like you can? Several ideas come to mind. (And please, forget the MSFT Windows style of things - that take several things iOS doesn't (yet?) have.) You need to (a) select an image, (b) highlight it, (c) pan it, (d) identify which image it was, and **most** importantly, (e) move it seamlessly while (f) at least adding it as a subview or image to a different view. I'm sure I missed a technical step or two, but hopefully I set up most of what you want.

Comment: @dfd I figured it out, please see the answer I provided. Looks like a lot but benefits your entire project (and future ones too!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved this with a combination of a few things. It looks like a lot to add, but it will come in handy in other projects.

**Step 1:** Enable the horizontal scrolling `UIScrollView` to "fail" both horizontally **and** vertically.

Although I only want my `UIScrollView` to scroll horizontally, I still need it to scroll vertically so that it can **fail** (explanation coming). Failing enables me to "pull" the subviews **out** of the `UIScrollView`.

The height of `scrollView` itself is `40` so the `contentSize` of the it must have a larger height for it to be able to *barely* scroll vertically.

```
self.effectTotalHeight.constant = 41
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: self.effectTotalHeight.constant)
```

Great! It scrolls vertically. But now the content rubber-bands (which we do not want). Against what others on SO say, do not go cheap and just disable bounce. (Especially if you want the bounce when scrolling horizontally!)

*Note: I also realized only disabling `Bounce Horizontally` in StoryBoard does... well, nothing (bug?).*

**Step 2:** Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to your View Controller class and detect scrolls

Now I want to detect the scroll and make sure that when scrolling vertically, it does not *actually* scroll. To do this, the `contentOffset.y` position should not change even though you are scrolling. `UIScrollViewDelegate` provides a delegate function `scrollViewDidScroll` that gets called when scrolling. Just set it as:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0.0
}
```

In order for this to be called, you need to set the delegate of the `scrollView` to `self` as well:

```
self.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Keep in mind this controls **all** `UIScrollView`s so provide an `if` statement or `switch` statement if you want it to only affect specific ones. In my case, this view controller only has one `UIScrollView` so I did not put anything.

Yay! So now it only scrolls horizontally again but this method only keeps the `contentOffset.y` at `0`. It **does not make it fail**. We do need it to because `scrollView` failing vertically is the key to enabling pan gesture recognizers (what lets you pull and drag etc.). So let's make it fail!

**Step 3:** Override `UIScrollView` default gesture recognition

In order to override any of the default gesture recognizers, we need to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` as another delegate method to your View Controller class.

The `scrollView` now needs its own pan gesture recognizer handler so that we can detect gestures on it. You also need to set the delegate of the new `scrollGesture` to `self` so we can detect it:

```
let scrollGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleScroll(_:)))
    scrollGesture.delegate = self
self.scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(scrollGesture)
```

Set up the `handleScroll` function:

```
func handleScroll(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // code here
}
```

This is all good, but why did we set this all up? Remember we disabled the contentOffset.y but the vertical scroll was not **failing**. Now we need to detect the direction of the scroll and let it fail if vertical so that `panHandle` can be activated.

**Step 4:** Detect gesture direction and let it fail (failure is good!)

I extended the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so that it can detect and emit directions by making the following public extension:

```
public enum Direction: Int {
   case Up
   case Down
   case Left
   case Right

   public var isX: Bool { return self == .Left || self == .Right }
   public var isY: Bool { return !isX }
}

public extension UIPanGestureRecognizer {
  public var direction: Direction? {
      let velo = velocity(in: view)
      let vertical = fabs(velo.y) > fabs(velo.x)
      switch (vertical, velo.x, velo.y) {
         case (true, _, let y) where y < 0: return .Up
         case (true, _, let y) where y > 0: return .Down
         case (false, let x, _) where x > 0: return .Right
         case (false, let x, _) where x < 0: return .Left
         default: return nil
      }
   }
}
```

Now in order to use it correctly, you can get the `recognizer`'s `.direction` inside of the `handleScroll` function and detect the emitted directions. In this case I am looking for either `.Up` or `.Down` and I want it to **emit a fail**. We do this by disabling the recognizer it, but then re-enabling it immediately after:

```
func handleScroll(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (recognizer.direction == .Up || recognizer.direction == .Down) {
        recognizer.isEnabled = false
        recognizer.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

The reason `.isEnabled` is immediately set to `true` right after `false` is because `false` will **emit the fail**, enabling the other gesture ("pulling out" (panning) its inner views), but to not be disabled forever (or else it will cease being called). By setting it back to `true`, it lets this listener be re-enabled right after emitting the fail.

**Step 5:** Let multiple gestures work by overriding each other

Last but not least, this is a very very important step as it allows both pan gestures and scroll gestures to work independently and not have one single one always override the other.

```
func gestureRecognizer(_: UIGestureRecognizer,
    shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

And that's that! This was a lot of research on SO (mostly finding what did not work) and experimentation but it all came together.

This was written with the expectation that you have already written the pan gesture recognizers of the objects inside of the scroll view that you are "pulling out" and how to handle its states (`.ended`, `.changed` etc.). I suggest if you need help with that, search SO. There are tons of answers.

If you have any other questions about this answer, please let me know.